# Javascript Toggle Active Class Only on Specific Elements?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I currently have this function that highlights my navbar menu items based on which one I clicked.

My problem is that I have a button inside of my navbar and it is getting the `highlight` class applied to it when I click on it.

I'm not sure how to write the Javascript to make sure when I click on it, it doesn't get the `highlight` class applied.

Here is the JS

```
      const menu = document.querySelector('#mobile-menu');
      const menuLinks = document.querySelector('.navbar__menu');

      const activeMenu = e => {
        const elems = document.querySelector('.highlight');
        const button = document.querySelector('.button');

        if (elems) {
          elems.classList.remove('highlight');
        }

        e.target.className = 'navbar__links highlight';
      };

      menuLinks.addEventListener('click', activeMenu);
```

Here is the HTML for the Navbar

```
    <ul class="navbar__menu">
      <li class="navbar__item">
        <a href="#home" class="navbar__links" id="homePage">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="navbar__item">
        <a href="#about" class="navbar__links" id="about-us">About 
     Us</a>
      </li>
      <li class="navbar__item">
        <a href="#services" class="navbar__links" 
    id="service">Services</a>
      </li>
      <li class="navbar__btn">
        <a href="#sign-up" class=" button" id="signup">Sign Up</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is complete working code which solves all your issues. When you click on `logo` it will add highlight `class` to homepage and will `check` window length is > 768 - You an event `listener` separately for logo to make sure we only add class to the homepage.

```
//logo event listener
logo.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (window.innerWidth > 768) {
    const homeMenu = document.querySelector('#homePage');
    homeMenu.classList.add('highlight');
  }
});
```

Also, to avoid highlight class getting adding to `signup` button you can simply check if clicked li item `id` is `not` signup using `getAttribute()` method.

```
// adds 'highlight' class to my menu item here - except the button
if (window.innerWidth > 768) {
  if (e.target.getAttribute('id') != 'signup') {
    e.target.classList.add('highlight');
  }
}
```

**Complete working demo:**

```js
const menu = document.querySelector('#mobile-menu');
const menuLinks = document.querySelector('.navbar__menu');
const logo = document.querySelector('#navbar__logo');

const activeMenu = e => {
  const elem = document.querySelector('.highlight');

  // adds 'highlight' class to my menu item here
  if (window.innerWidth > 768) {
    if (e.target.getAttribute('id') != 'signup') {
      e.target.classList.add('highlight');
    }
  }

  //Remove class from others when click on li
  if (elem && window.innerWidth < 768 || elem) {
    elem.classList.remove('highlight');
  }
};

//Click event on li
menuLinks.addEventListener('click', activeMenu);

//logo event listener
logo.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (window.innerWidth > 768) {
    const homeMenu = document.querySelector('#homePage');
    homeMenu.classList.add('highlight');
  }
});


//on resize
window.addEventListener('resize', function(event) {
  const links = document.querySelectorAll('.navbar__links');
  links.forEach(function(x) {
    if (window.innerWidth < 768) {
      x.classList.remove('highlight'); //remove highlught class
    }
  })
});
```

```css
.highlight {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<a href="#home" id="navbar__logo">COLOR</a>
<div class="navbar__toggle" id="mobile-menu">
  <span class="bar"></span> <span class="bar"></span>
  <span class="bar"></span>
</div>

<ul class="navbar__menu">
  <li class="navbar__item">
    <a href="#home" class="navbar__links" id="homePage">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="navbar__item">
    <a href="#about" class="navbar__links" id="about-us">About
      Us</a>
  </li>
  <li class="navbar__item">
    <a href="#services" class="navbar__links" id="service">Services</a>
  </li>
  <li class="navbar__btn">
    <a href="#sign-up" class="button" id="signup">Sign Up</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you don't need to listen for `click` event on each item in your menu. You could (should) listen for `click` event in your `<ul class="navbar__menu">` and use the property `target` of the event to find out which item has been clicked on.

Secondly, to answer your question, to remove `highlight` class from the previous selected item you should do `document.querySelector('.highlight').classList.remove('highlight');` and then add the class to the new selected item.

code could be something like that

```js
menuLinks.addEventListener('click', evt => {
  // remove previous selected item highlight class
  document.querySelector('.highlight').classList.remove('highlight');

  // add highlight class
  evt.target.classList.add('highlight');
});
```

Comment: yeah so how would I write the code? I understand the logic, but I don't know how to actually write that out

Comment: but how does it know which menu item I am clicking on? I don't get how to refactor my code to only target the menuLinks and look for the target

Comment: Even if your listening `click` event on `<ul>` evt.target will be the actual element which has been clicked on, in your case `<a>`. Check [Event bubbling and capture](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events).

Comment: Update: I figured out how to add the `highlight` class, but now my issue is the button gets the highlight class applied to it and I don't want that. Do you know how to prevent the button from having the `highlight` class applied?